# how to make my GroupBox/StackPanel scrollable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

```
<GroupBox x:Name="groupBox1" Header="Item1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,94,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="179" Width="280">
            <StackPanel>
                <RadioButton GroupName="County" Content="County1" IsChecked="True"/>
                <RadioButton GroupName="County" Content="County2" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="County" Content="County3" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="County" Content="County4" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="County" Content="County5" />
                <RadioButton GroupName="County" Content="County6" />
```

My list is very long so I only show the first 6

My UI shows the RadioButton but it keeps going beyond the GroupBox. So Can I make the StackPanel or GroupBox scrollable?

I've tried adding this to my StackPanel but didnt work

```
<StackPanel ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" CanVerticallyScroll="True">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Wrap a `ScrollViewer` around your `StackPanel`.

```
<ScrollViewer>
   <StackPanel>
      ...
   </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: WOW. I would never have thought about that. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Software *is* fun, and sometimes, it's easy too. :-)